# Carousel/Slider with Angular 2 from scratch

Tags: angular, typescript, carousel

I am trying to code a carousel/slider with Angular 2. Idea in my mind is, I have a array of images,

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  images: Array<any> = [
    {
      image: "1.jpg"
    },
    {
      image: "2.jpg"
    },
    {
      image: "3.jpg"
    },
    {
      image: "4.jpg"
    },
    {
      image: "5.jpg"
    },
    {
      image: "6.jpg"
    }
  ];
}
```

I want to loop through the image array and replace the background image of a div with the current value of `{{images.image}}`.

I have set up a counter,

```
public subscription: any;
public time: any;
ngOnInit() {
  let timer = TimerObservable.create(1000,5000);
  this.subscription = timer.subscribe(t=>{
    this.time = t;
  })
}
```

and the target `div` would look something like

```
<div class="slider__home" style="background: url({{image}})">

</div>
```

How do I achieve this? I don't want to use bootstrap or jQuery, but just plain Angular2, thanks for any help.

Comment: *"How do I achieve this?"* is not an appropriate question for SO. The answer is: you write some code and figure it out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can't get started because I have no clue about what to do. Always have used jQ. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Then you are not yet ready for a question on Stack Overflow. Go and read some tutorials, so some research, try things out.

Comment: Its Angular 2 and it is still on rc6 which does not have any good/(at least one) tutorials on carousel!

Comment: That's unfortunate, but still not an appropriate question. Maybe once you figure it out you can be the one that writes that missing tutorial?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982356/angular-2-slider-which-slider-to-use/42930634#42930634   See this answer

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<div class="slider__home" [style.background]="'url('+ image +')'">

</div>
```

Comment: How do I loop through the list? `*ngFor` seems unusable here!

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstrap carousel like this:

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Insert all css data here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <carousel></carousel>

        <!-- Insert all needed scripts here -->
        <script>
            System.import('carousel.js');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

carousel.html

```
<div id="carousel-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div *ngFor="let url of urls" class="item" [ngClass]="{active: isActive(url)}">
            <img src="{{url}}" alt="{{url}}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

carousel.ts

```
// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
// <reference path="boodstrap.d.ts" />

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: "carousel",
    templateUrl: 'carousel.html'
})

export class CarouselComponent {
    private start = false;
    urls = [];
    constructor(http: Http) {
            http.get('/getcarousel')
                .subscribe(res => this.startCarousel(res.json()));        
    }

    startCarousel(urls: string[]) {
        this.urls = urls;
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    }

    isActive(url: string) {
        return url === this.urls[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just wrote an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982356/angular-2-slider-which-slider-to-use/42930634#42930634) which is similar to your question.

If you want to learn how create a content slider from scratch, [here on by blog](http://www.ravinderpayal.com/Simple-and-Light-Weight-Image-or-Content-Slider-for-Angular2/), it's well explained. You will be able to create an light weight slider in pure angular 2 and css, and it will be as simple as the following example in use.

```
typescript
 @Component({
        selector: 'ImageShow',
        template: `
        <contentSlider [slides]="images"></contentSlider>
        `
    })
    export class ImageShowComponent implements  AfterViewInit{
       images:Array<any> = [{"sType":"img","imgSrc":"..."},{"sType":"div","content":"...Hello It's slidable content"}];
      constructor(){
      }
}
```